# Why ValueError is not displayed

Tags: python

so basically my code is :

```
def process_contacts(contacts_file):
    f = None
    sections = []
    ret_dic = {}
    try:
        f = open(contacts_file, 'r')
        content = f.readlines()
        for line in content:
            if "#" in line:
                continue
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            sections = line.split(',')               # section = categories of information on origin file
            if sections[1] == '' or len(sections) != 4:
                raise ValueError('Invalid input file')
            if sections[3] in ret_dic:
                    if sections[1] not in ret_dic[sections[3]]:
                        ret_dic[sections[3]].append(sections[1])
            else:
                ret_dic[sections[3]] = [sections[1]]
    except IOError:
        print 'Cannot process due to an IO error'
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Invalid input file')
    finally:
        if f != None:
            f.close()
        if sections != []:
            return ret_dic
```

I'm having problem with `ValueError` raising. I need the `ValueError` to be raised as an error, but my code just skips over it and I don't understand why, I searched the whole internet about it, but perhaps I just don't get it.
Anyways the csv file that I open is :

```
Avi,Levi,Kushnir 7,Jerusalem
Moshe,,Hamakabim 4,Tel Aviv
Michael,Cohen,Herzel 70
Eli,Cohen,Haroe 6,Jerusalem
Moti,Cohen,shalom 5,Tel Aviv
```

Comment: good practice is to put as little in the `try:` statement as possible - for exactly this reason. It's easy for something other than the expected line to raise the error and it makes it much harder to debug.

Comment: 1) print each line and each of the conditions. 2) try to raise ValueError inconditionally just to see what happens 3) fix indentation

Comment: also, `csv` module is built for that parsing.

Comment: the easiest way to get the indentation to work is to paste the whole block and then hit the SO code block button - this could be caused by odd indentation, but I can't tell whether the bad indentation is in your code (unlikely) or just your question. :)

Comment: as @Jean-FrançoisFabre says - using the csv module takes a lot of this work out of your hands, or perhaps pandas, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Good comments all, but no one is addressing why the `raise ValueError` in the `except` doesn't seem to be firing. After some testing OP is getting into his `if` block in the `try`, the exception is being raised, and the `except` is catching it. For the life of me, I don't know why the exception isn't being re-raised. 

To clarify. As far as I can tell, the program gets to the `raise` in the `except` but then continue. There is no Traceback.

Comment: The `return` in the `finally` block overrules the pending exception.

Comment: my main question is why the ValueError in the try sequence doesnt raise first to begin with ?

Comment: It does. You catch it with the `except`, try to re-raise it, but the return in the `finally` stops it from being re-raised.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your `finally` block. You `raise` your `ValueError` in the `except` and then say "oh never mind" and finish out with the `finally`. `finally` blocks will *always* be the last thing that runs if an error is encountered.

Comment: I think it's actually because the `finally` block contains a `return` that the exception is abandoned. Otherwise the `finally` would complete normally, and then the exception-raising would be resumed.

Comment: but the ValueError in the Try isnt raised in the first place ? I want the program to end as soon is ValueError encounters which is in the try sequence

Comment: Then don't catch the error with an `except`. The point of an `except` block is to stop an error from being raised and do something different instead.